# iOS 8 MathJax / safari browser bugs

Tags: bug, mathjax

When I use an iPad air under iOS 8.2 I experience two problems lately:

- large braces are shifted down 50% vertically, this seems to include the \left* \right* constructs, like | in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955480/show-that-left-sum-s-theta-z-k-right-left-sum-s-theta-e/955507#955507). 
  See screen shot below:

---

[image: screen shot]

---

- safari rather often freezes during editing, usually when using the delete backwards key (<=x=), then crashes

Some more examples of the rendering problem:

- [large curly brace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961920/how-to-get-back-the-first-form-in-terms-of-absolute-function-from-the-component)

---

[image: screen shot]

---

- [square brackets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961653/checking-if-a-matrix-is-positive-semidefinite)

---

[image: screen shot]

---

- [parentheses and more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961515/prove-2f-1-left-beginarrayc-tfrac16-tfrac23-tfrac56-endarray-middle)

---

[image: screen shot]

---

Comment: I saw the same hang-while-editing on my older iPad.